# How can I change the color of tabPanel title on the server side?

Tags: colors, shiny, tabpanel

In Shiny, on the UI side my code is:

```
mainPanel(uiOutput('my_tabsetpanel'))
```

and on the Server side I have:

```
output$my_tabsetpanel <- renderUI({
    tabPanel(mytabtitle, DT::dataTableOutput(id))
})
```

How can I change only the color of the tab title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the title in a `div` and change the style.

Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel(uiOutput('my_tabsetpanel'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$my_tabsetpanel <- renderUI({
        tabsetPanel(tabPanel(div("mytabtitle", style = "color: red;"), "my content"))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! you sorted out my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to have the titles of the inactive tabs in red, and the title of the active tab in blue:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML("li>a {color: red;} .nav-tabs>li.active>a {color: blue;}"))),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", p("plot")),
        tabPanel("Summary", p("summary")),
        tabPanel("Table", p("table"))
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(...){}
)
```

Comment: I guess I cannot use this on the server side, right?

Comment: @armtar Sorry I don't see what you mean.

Comment: I want to format the tab title in server.R, not ui.R. Probably it is obvious, but I am a newbie to Shiny; and on top of it, no idea about HTML/CSS.

Comment: I found this, which is similar I guess:  tabPanel(title=HTML('<span style="color:red;">',"tabtitle",'&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a>'), DT::dataTableOutput(id)))